# What's the name of the song playing when Mr. 3 uses his Wax Wax Mansion ability on Luffy during the Little Garden Arc?

Tags: one-piece, music

What is the song playing when Mr. 3 uses his Wax Wax Mansion ability on Luffy during the Little Garden arc (I think it's episode 75 ish)? I've been searching for it ever since I heard it, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32EmX1eO5Xo&ab_channel=MrCyboron
Here is the sound track. Most One Piece official soundtracks will come with at least more than one song. The soundtrack you're looking for will be the second of two soundtracks.
EDIT: The name of the soundtrack is Difficult.

Comment: All tough it is nice that you got the song in there, it still does not answer the OP's question. Which is What is the name of the song, if you were to include that this would answer the question.

Comment: OP said "What is the song...", not the name of the song.

Comment: I quote: "What's the name of the song playing when Mr. 3 uses his Wax Wax Mansion ability on Luffy during the Little Garden Arc?". It is the title of the question. So please edit your answer to include a name.